# How to show column from another table in list_display without foreign key relation?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-admin

I have these database relationships:

[image: database relations]

Now in my `admin.py` in the `list_display` I want to display the orders table plus the quantity row from order_items. To do so, I would use this sql query:

```
SELECT
    order_id, quantity 
FROM
    orders
INNER JOIN
        order_items
    ON
        orders.order_id = order_items.order_id;
```

Now I don't know how to do this in the correct way with django without using a raw query.

So what do I add in the line

`list_display = ('order_id')`

in order to show the quantity row?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to get the quantity for order_items for a particular related order write the following code -

```
>>> from django.db.models import Sum
>>> order.order_items_set.aggregate(quantity=Sum('quantity'))
```

It will return you a dictionary like - `{'quantity': 3}`
Refer to [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/aggregation/) for more information about aggregations

In order to show it in your Admin for Order model -

```
class OrderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'user_id', 'status', 'created_at', 'get_quantity')

    class Meta:
        model = Order

    def get_quantity(self, obj):
        result = obj.order_items_set.aggregate(quantity=Sum('quantity'))
        return result.get('quantity',0)

    get_quantity.short_description = 'Quantity'

admin.site.register(Order, OrderAdmin)
```

Refer to [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/) to know more about django-admin customizations.